# Use another field value as condition in Entity Query

Tags: 8, database

I'm performing in Drupal 8 an **entity query** that searches for nodes that have not been changed since x days, where x is a numeric node field (node.field_days).
So I would like to perform a query like:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery("node")
  ->condition('changed', strtotime('-node.field_days days'), '<=');
```

I know that condition takes as value a string and not a db column, but is it possible to use entity query with a dynamic value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entity query is a powerful and convenient tool to query for content and config entities that have certain properties/field values/field references.

Yet, it has its limitations. Comparing two fields is not possible using the generic entity query and its condition method.

For such a task, you may need to use the more low level [dynamic (select) queries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries) and its [where](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21SelectExtender.php/function/SelectExtender%3A%3Awhere/8.6.x) method. An example for your use case:

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
// Query node base field table.
$query = $connection->select('node_field_data', 'n');
// Join with the `field_days` field table.
$query->leftjoin('node__field_days', 'd', 'd.entity_id = n.nid');
// Query for the node ID.
$query->fields('n', ['nid']);
// Your condition (a day has 86400 seconds; we multiply them with
// the value of the field_days field, add them to the changed
// timestamp of the node and compare it against the current time).
$query->where('n.changed + (d.field_days_value * 86400) <= :now', [
  ':now' => \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime(),
]);
// Optional sorting.
$query->orderBy('n.changed', 'DESC');
// Fetch results.
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed(0, 0);
```

Above example assumes:

1. that you used a numeric field type for `field_days`, so its database stored value can be multiplied with seconds without any casting,
2. that the `field_days` field allows one value only, so we can safely ignore field deltas when joining,
3. that `field_days` is present on all nodes/bundles and has a valid value,
4. that you use one language only in your site/the `field_days` value is not translatable, so we can also ignore langcodes.

You may have to alter the query accordingly, if any of these assumptions is not true.

Comment: Why do you think this isn't supported by EntityQuery? Is it because it would be ambiguous weather the second argument of the condition referred to a string literal or the a field name?